# Is it possible to set cases as "read only" for all users except the owner while the case is open?

Tags: read-only

Basically, we only want the case to be able to be edited by the case owner so that multiple users aren't stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: The short answer is Yes. It will depend on your sharing and security model. You can have a private OWD, and then can utilize a criteria based sharing to allow Users to be able to edit case only when it reaches a particular stage. But it all depends on how your sharing/security has been designed.